# Empty Bibliography error despite implementing multiple fixes?

Tags: biblatex, citing, compiling

I have been trying to sort this out for almost a straight day and any fix I find for similar problems doesn't seem to work. I am using TeXStudio to write my thesis and my bibliography isn't being included at the end of my file, nor is the file referencing properly.

My main file preamble is as:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, 
english, 
singlespacing, 
nolistspacing, 
headsepline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{Bibl.bib}
```

and my bibliography is as follows:

```
@misc{Missi34:online,
author = {},
title = {Mission | UoS3},
howpublished = {\url{http://generic.wordpress.soton.ac.uk/uos3/mission/}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 04/11/2016)}
}

@article {GRL:GRL13482,
author = {Anderson, Brian J. and Takahashi, Kazue and Toth, Bruce A.},
title = {Sensing global Birkeland currents with iridium® engineering magnetometer data},
journal = {Geophysical Research Letters},
volume = {27},
number = {24},
issn = {1944-8007},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2000GL000094},
doi = {10.1029/2000GL000094},
pages = {4045--4048},
keywords = {Magnetospheric Physics: Instruments and techniques},
year = {2000},
}

@misc{DICE83:online,
author = {},
title = {DICE - eoPortal Directory - Satellite Missions},
howpublished = {\url{https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/d/dice#foot17%29}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 04/12/2016)}
}

@manual{CoilManual,
title = {Gyroskop U 52006},
date = {2015},
OPTlanguage = {English},
OPTorganization = {3B Scientific},
OPTpagetotal = {3},
OPTurl = {\url{https://www.3bscientific.co.uk/product-manual/1000906_EN.pdf}},
OPTurldate = {(Accessed on 04/13/2016)},
}
```

It claims that the bibliography is empty at the `\printbibliography` line even though I have been citing them in my main text. When I go the cite something the list of references appears but puts just the label in the text instead of number or information. For example,

> The product manual (CoilManual) gives an equation to calculate the ﬁeld generated inside the coils.

I have tried using `\cite`, `\cite*` and `\autocite` and nothing helps.

I have done the `pdflatex`-`biber`-`pdflatex` sequence many times, have ensured that my default bibliograghy is `biber` and not `bibtex`. It may just be something small but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: if there is, what is the exact error/warning message you get?

Comment: Note that your `.bib` file is not optimised for `biblatex`, you can use the `url` and `urldate` field instead of `note` and `howpublished`. The code so far looks OK, though I don't know if `MastersDoctoralThesis` can cause some trouble here. We would need to see the errors and warnings from the `.log` and`.blg` files. [Check also if your editor is really set up correctly.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors and problems you get are comming from one bad bib entry.

Please see this changes for the bib entry `DICE83:online`:

```
@online{DICE83:online,
  author = {},
  title  = {DICE - eoPortal Directory - Satellite Missions},
  url    = {https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/d/dice#foot17%29},
  urldate = {2016-12-04},
}
```

The problem in the old version is the `%`, causing that the field `howpublished` is never ended ...

With the changes above I can compile without error messages the following complete MWE (package `filecontents` only used to have bib file and TeX code concatenated to one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Missi34:online,
author = {},
title = {Mission | UoS3},
howpublished = {\url{http://generic.wordpress.soton.ac.uk/uos3/mission/}},
month = {},
year = {},
note = {(Accessed on 04/11/2016)}
}

@article {GRL:GRL13482,
author = {Anderson, Brian J. and Takahashi, Kazue and Toth, Bruce A.},
title = {Sensing global Birkeland currents with iridium® engineering magnetometer data},
journal = {Geophysical Research Letters},
volume = {27},
number = {24},
issn = {1944-8007},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2000GL000094},
doi = {10.1029/2000GL000094},
pages = {4045--4048},
keywords = {Magnetospheric Physics: Instruments and techniques},
year = {2000},
}

@online{DICE83:online,
  author = {},
  title  = {DICE - eoPortal Directory - Satellite Missions},
  url    = {https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/d/dice#foot17%29},
  urldate = {2016-12-04},
}

@manual{CoilManual,
title = {Gyroskop U 52006},
date = {2015},
OPTlanguage = {English},
OPTorganization = {3B Scientific},
OPTpagetotal = {3},
OPTurl = {\url{https://www.3bscientific.co.uk/product-manual/1000906_EN.pdf}},
OPTurldate = {(Accessed on 04/13/2016)},
}
\end{filecontents*}


%\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\documentclass[%
  english,
  11pt, 
  singlespacing, 
  nolistspacing, 
  headsepline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, 
  style=authoryear,
  natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Some Text.\nocite{*}

\printbibliography%[]
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of bibliography]

Conclusion:

If you use `biblatex` then please rework your BiB file because `biblatex` uses other field names (`url` instead of `howpublished`, etc.).  If you want to use the advantages of `biblatex` please use the field names, `biblatex` is made for.